# How to extracting values of 40 plots from different bands of raster image in R?

Tags: raster, r, band

```
I have 40 plots(samples) and I want to extract corresponding values from different bands of RapidEye image. So at the end I want to have totally 200 values of 5 bands in the format of txt.
Till now I could open the image and different bands separately. I used:

>library(raster)
>library(rgdal)
>library(glcm)

>band1<- raster("D:\\MSc\\Imagedata\\Clipped\\Extent_bavaria.tif", band=1, values=TRUE)
>band2<- raster("D:\\MSc\\Imagedata\\Clipped\\Extent_bavaria.tif", band=2, values=TRUE)
>band3<- raster("D:\\MSc\\Imagedata\\Clipped\\Extent_bavaria.tif", band=3, values=TRUE)
>band4<- raster("D:\\MSc\\Imagedata\\Clipped\\Extent_bavaria.tif", band=4, values=TRUE)
>band5<- raster("D:\\MSc\\Imagedata\\Clipped\\Extent_bavaria.tif", band=5, values=TRUE)


>image_stack <- stack(band1,band2,band3,band4,band5)
>plot(image_stack)

I have my samples in the format of (.shp) and also (.xlsx) with coordinates. Now I want to find the value for each of my samples in each band of the image.
```

Comment: `result <- extract(rapideyeraster, samplevector)`. Check out `?extract` for more information

Comment: You mean I should only add my raster and vector layers?

Comment: You have the coordinates of the sample points, haven't you? Have you already imported your RapidEye raster and your samples into R?

Comment: Yes I have them and I have opened my raster in R but I couldn't succeed to open my samples.

Comment: Did you get an error message? Could you please provide more information about your data and what you have done so far. Please update your question unsing the "edit" button below. And by the way, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Thank you, I completed my explanation. I am new in Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: I did not get an error I even install the package of shapefiles but it can not read this comment: x=read.shapefile(shape.name)

Comment: you can use `x=shapefile(shape.name)` from the raster package

Comment: and I think, its enough to import the entire stack like this: `image_stack <- stack("D:\MSc\Imagedata\Clipped\Extent_bavaria.tif")` and if necessary assign the bandnames with `names(image_stack) <-c("band1", "band2","band3","band4","band5")`

Comment: Thanks very helpful, it worked finally. But how can I show my samples on top of my raster image? because when I plot shape file, I miss my raster.

Comment: there are several possibilites. Check out ggplot2 or xyplot, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166234/ggplot2-adding-points-from-a-different-dataset-and-a-raster-matrix-data-to-a-pl

Comment: I made an answer out of my comments. If it answers your question please accept it as answer. Have fun with R! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#load packages
library(raster)

#import files
raster <- stack("D:\MSc\Imagedata\Clipped\Extent_bavaria.tif")
names(raster) <-c("band1", "band2","band3","band4","band5") #rename band names
vector=shapefile("nameofyourshapefile.shp")

# extract the numbers where vector and raster overlay
result <- extract(raster, vector) #see ?extract for additional useful options (e.g. "fun")

#write output file as .txt
write.table(result, "result.txt",  row.names=FALSE)  #row.names=F removes the automatic numbering of the columns
```

Comment: I got an error after running result : not compatible with requested type

Comment: You got this error in this line: result <- extract(raster, vector)? Or when you try to write a table?

Comment: I actually solved the error problem. I had to change also the coordinate system of the shape file layer. But still I have a problem with the null values in the table that I get for extracted values from the bands. The X of the points are bigger than the xmin of the image thats why I get null values. I think I have to solve this problem first to get correct values. Thanks for your attention BTW :)